# How to correctly chain imported interceptors

Tags: angular

I am using angular-oauth2-oidc, Angular 7. I believe it imports an interceptor with its import

```
OAuthModule.forRoot({
       resourceServer: {
         allowedUrls: [environment.backendUrl],
         sendAccessToken: true
       }
     })
```

Additionally I have an interceptor completing an url, which allows me to use only relative paths within httpClient calls of services. e.g.

```
this.httpClient.get('/resource/' + id)
```

Which is then intercepted to a complete url to the backend

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        if (!req.url.startsWith('/') || req.url.startsWith('/assets')) {
            return next.handle(req);
        }

        const modifiedUrl: string = environment.backendUrl + req.url;
        const modifiedRequest = req.clone({ url: modifiedUrl });

        return next.handle(modifiedRequest);
    }
```

Before the url is intercepted the imported Interceptor obviously can't work.

How can I ensure, that the imported interceptor is coming after the own interceptor in chain?

As a temporary solution I added '/' to the allowedUrls, but I don't like this workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well angular applies interceptor in the order that you provided them. From the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#interceptor-order):

> Angular applies interceptors in the order that you provide them. If you provide interceptors A, then B, then C, requests will flow in A->B->C and responses will flow out C->B->A.
>
> You cannot change the order or remove interceptors later. If you need
> to enable and disable an interceptor dynamically, you'll have to build
> that capability into the interceptor itself.

So i guess you need to tell to your module to not provide the interceptor and declare it yourself.

Taking a quick look at the [lib documentation](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/working-with-httpinterceptors.html) you have no choice than using sendAccessToken to false and implement a custom interceptor that do the job.

```
import { Injectable, Inject, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService, OAuthStorage } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { OAuthResourceServerErrorHandler } from "./resource-server-error-handler";
import { OAuthModuleConfig } from "../oauth-module.config";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultOAuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(
        private authStorage: OAuthStorage,
        private errorHandler: OAuthResourceServerErrorHandler,
        @Optional() private moduleConfig: OAuthModuleConfig
    ) {
    }

    private checkUrl(url: string): boolean {
        let found = this.moduleConfig.resourceServer.allowedUrls.find(u => url.startsWith(u));
        return !!found;
    }

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let url = req.url.toLowerCase();

        if (!this.moduleConfig) return next.handle(req);
        if (!this.moduleConfig.resourceServer) return next.handle(req);
        if (!this.moduleConfig.resourceServer.allowedUrls) return next.handle(req);
        if (!this.checkUrl(url)) return next.handle(req);

        let sendAccessToken = this.moduleConfig.resourceServer.sendAccessToken;

        if (sendAccessToken) {

            let token = this.authStorage.getItem('access_token');
            let header = 'Bearer ' + token;

            let headers = req.headers
                                .set('Authorization', header);

            req = req.clone({ headers });
        }

        return next.handle(req).catch(err => this.errorHandler.handleError(err));

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had the feeling my question would result in this answer. Anyway, I think I keep my workaround (adding '/' to allowedUrls) then.